# SQLite Full Text Search Snippet Function only returns first matched string

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search

suppose i am searching a string called "stories" in 3 diffrent chapter and all chapter contains this word ("stories") more then 1.

the snipet function only returns 3 result (1 matches of the every chapter) instead of all matches

here is the snippet query :

SELECT snippet(Chapters) FROM Chapters WHERE Chapters MATCH 'stories'

Comment: If a `Chapters` contains the string, it matches and returns that chapter.  What behavior do you want/expect?

Comment: chapter have 4 matches but it returns only 1 result like

 <b>...</b>aaaaaa <b>stories</b> aaaaaaa<b>...</b>


here it should return 4 different - different snippet of the matched content

Comment: The current behavior of text matching is correct.

Comment: so what about other matches ? i mean how can i trace those missing records?

Comment: Do you want all chapters where `stories` appears 3 or more times?

Comment: i have total 3 chapter , 

chapter1 

chapter2

chapter3


now chapter2 contains "stories" word in 4 diff- diff places so i want all 4 difererent matched snippet content
  
same for chapter1 and chapter3 if match found then it should return snippet of matches word